# Element in WPF is not registered to an event: PropertyChanged

Tags: wpf, mvvm, label, bind

I have a `Lable` in `Xaml` is supposed to bind to a particular variable.

(I'm guessing that his binding is causing the problem, the question is why!)

Here:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Model.SomeCls,Path=Person.Name}" />
```

It goes something like this:

DataContext=ViewModel->Model-> SomeCls-> Person -> **Name** (Name have NotifyPropertyChanged function)

When it comes to the function NotifyPropertyChanged the PropertyChanged event is null.

I realized it was probably because not registered to an event.

Do I need on each variable I use them to get to name to put the function NotifyPropertyChanged??  **(sounds a bit weird)** Or am I missing something else?

**PS**

There are no binding errors in the output window!!!

Comment: have you read this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx

Comment: @paul Yes! I want notification only when the name is changing, it is possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Does your label bind the first time but not change, or does it never bind?

Comment: @paul I think it's bind the first time (the first time it empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binding is wrong, should be defiened like that:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=Model.SomeCls.Person.Name}" />
```

Comment: I put my xaml, what code to put in addition to that? The variable I want to reach him is merely found in the variables tree, no special function or something similar.